# How to recover from a state where a remote cannot be fully deleted?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have run `git remote remove origin`, but the remote `origin` doesn't get fully removed.

Now when I run `git remote -v`, it lists `origin`, but does not give any URL next to it.

All other `git remote` commands will tell me `error: No such remote: 'origin'`.

There is no mention of `origin` in `.git/config`.

I have tried re-adding an `origin` remote, then fetching from it, then removing it again. These commands are all successful but they leave me in the same state.

Any ideas how I can make git forget about this `origin` remote?

[Background: The repo uses `git-lfs`, and I regularly get `smudge filter lfs failed` errors when merging/rebasing from `upstream` (the main company repo), and the only workaround I have found is to delete all remotes, re-add `upstream`, fetch, then do the merge/rebase before adding back any additional remotes. This stubborn corrupt remote is preventing this process from working.]

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please explain what was wrong with having "Git" in the title, or having this tagged with "corruption"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: May it's in the global `~/.gitconfig`. Compare your output from `git config --get-regexp --local "remote\.*"` with `git config --get-regexp --global "remote\.*"`

Comment: @phd That was it! I had a `puttykeyfile` under `[remote "origin"]` in my `~/.gitconfig`, and removing those made my day. If you make this an answer rather than a comment, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be from the global `~/.gitconfig`. Find it out with

```
git config --get-regexp --global "remote\.*"
```

or

```
git config --list --show-origin | grep -Fw origin
```

PS. Hm, hmm, `--show-origin` is about a different kind of "origin". :-)

Answer (score 1):

git stores all its metadata in the `.git` subdirectory of your repo. If we can find the right place to edit in that directory, we should be able to fix your repo.

You can find some information about how information is stored in the git book:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

After some exploring, I recommend looking in a couple places:

- `.git/config`: has a section for each remote. If there is a section for origin, delete it.
- `.git/refs/remotes`: has a directory for each remote, with a file for each branch in that remote. If there is a directory called origin, delete it.

The actual repository data is stored in `.git/objects`. As long as you don't start deleting files in that directory you won't lose your repository contents :)